# How can I stop keyboard-quit from ending macro definition?

Tags: keyboard-macros

When I am defining keyboard macro with `kmacro-start-macro` and I press `C-g` (for example to deactivate mark or I press it accidentally), macro definition is aborted and I have to start over. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some function like this, to only run `keyboard-quit` if no macro is running, and bind to `C-g`:

```
(defun keyboard-quit-only-if-no-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (if defining-kbd-macro
      (progn
        (if (region-active-p)
            (deactivate-mark)
          (message "Macro running. Can't quit.")))

    (keyboard-quit)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-g") 'keyboard-quit-only-if-no-macro)
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some variable to set to make this simpler. It seems that it's very basic and should be customizable but I looked at definition at `keyboard-quit` and quitting macros is hardcoded there.